# DWR: access converted object methods

Tags: java, dwr

DWR is general works great when all I want to do is access some property of a converted JS Object, but not so well when I want to access a method of said object.

```
<dwr:convert type="bean" class="domain.Fund" javascript="JFund">
    <dwr:include method="id,name,availableBalance"/>
</dwr:convert>

public double getAvailableBalance(short var) {
    ...
}
```

I have tried many different types of configurations of the Fund object to get access to the `availableBalance` method, but I haven't had any luck.  I cannot explicitly declare `getAvailableBalance` in the include method list as this throws an error.  I know DWR calls the getters of the properties, but i haven't found a way to specify a property whose getter method takes in a parameter.

If i make a DB call and am returned a Fund object, doing something like this in JS always results in an undefined error message

```
fund.availableBalance(1);
fund.getAvailableBalance(1);
```

but these work find as expected

```
fund.id;
fund.name
```

Any idea on how to access methods and pass in parameters?

Comment: What version of dwr are you using? from where did you get this syntax?

Comment: DWR 2.06, documentation for spring config